# SSLPinning on .net standard 2.1

Tags: c#, httpclient, .net-standard

I want to check the certificate during the negotiation time of an HttpRequest made over an  System.Net.Http HttpClient. I found there are multiple ways to do it, one of it is with:

`ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(VerifyServer);`

Which I don't like because I want to do it per HttpClient. I've notice I can inject a HttpClientHandler through the constructor, but the method I want to use to check the thumbprint of the certificate is hidden:

```
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
public Func<HttpRequestMessage, X509Certificate2, X509Chain, SslPolicyErrors, bool> ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback { get; set; }
```

Is there any specific reason why is hidden? Is it safe to use this method to check the certificate?

Thanks!

Comment: I believe this is happening due to 'method hiding', since you have implemented a new instance of the RemoteCertificateValidationCallback and you assing it to ServerCertificateValidationCallback  of ServicePointManager. Check the following article i believe you will find it helpful, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/method-hiding-in-c-sharp/

Comment: That's the method in the .net Standard 2.1 library, so nothing I have hidden. Just wondering why it's hidden, and if it's safe to use

Comment: if you use both your statement ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(VerifyServer); 

the ServerCertificateValidationCallback  of the base class is going to be hidden